# An implement of Constructing elliptic curves of prescribed order

Tags: algorithms, elliptic-curves

In the Reinier Bröker's Phd thesis——Constructing elliptic curves of prescribed order(2006), he present a effective way to generate a elliptic curve with a given order N. And the heuristic run time of the algorithm is O(2<sup>ω(N)</sup> (logN)<sup>4+ε</sup>) . I want use the scheme in my system. However, I don't know how to implement the scheme.

The algorithm has been presented almost 10 years. There must have someone has implemented the algorithm. Does anyone know where could I find the implementation of the scheme?